# Creating Microsoft external user account using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a windows liveID accounts using windows live admin center SDK using a different domain.

My question is, Has anyone tried using this liveId as external user in SharePoint Online site?
Thanks
Nate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature for SharePoint Online to invite external users to a site automatically, and to programmatically invite external users, it is not possible. The reason is that SharePoint Online creates a unique invitation id per invitation, and each invitation can only be accepted once. Based on my understanding, it is impossible to get a random and unique invitation id created by SharePoint Online.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/160998.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aanchal. Can I programatically create liveid's and use them as external users?

Comment: You can add external user from sharepoint online site as : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/42608001-66cf-46be-81e3-5acf357089be/how-to-add-external-users-to-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicesadministrationcenter

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/manage-sharing-with-external-users-HA102849862.aspx

Comment: Can we programatically identify whether the site is externally shared, and the list of users and their permissions ..?